# Is there a name to the art style used in No Game No Life?

Tags: no-game-no-life

I haven't seen an anime before No Game No life that uses such vibrant colors before, and I thought that it might have been unique to it. However I recently watched A Dark Rabbit Has 7 Lives and it uses an extremely similar style of art, so now I'm wondering what the style is called so that I can look up more work with it.

Comment: Both of them are illustrated by the same person, and it's his art style.

Comment: Also this bright art style is used in Sakurasou no pet kanjo but i don't think it has a name

Comment: [Harue Ono](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=22273) did the color scheme and design for the anime series and many other ones that you may be familiar with.